# How do I write an OSX  device driver for a USB WiMax modem?

Tags: macos, usb, driver, device

I am planing to spend few days a week writing a driver for a Greenpacket USB WiMax modem. Greenpacket only provides Windows driver with it and as I am fond of Linux and Mac I feel very bad not having driver for them.

I have experience writing C++ programs so I think it won't be hard for me. Even I like C++ programming very much. I have never written drivers but I know some concepts. I have PDF of the [device specification](http://www.greenpacket.com/downloads/devices/wimax/datasheets/usb/WiMAX-USB-Modem-UH235.pdf) from the company's website.

I would like to ask if I can write driver with that provided specifications? If yes what would be my starting point assuming I would like to write it for MAC first and then Linux. I am reading [this article](http://wagerlabs.com/writing-a-mac-osx-usb-device-driver-that-impl) right now but your experiences would be of great help.

Comment: Please don't use URL shortening services! We programmers like to know what site we're about to visit before clicking on a link.

Comment: OK I will re-write it but it was too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product specifications sheet does not provide enough data to write a device driver. You are going to need low-level information about how to speak with the WiMax device via USB. You are *probably* also way out of your depth of you think a product sheet is enough information to write a device driver.

Comment: Yes I had the exact thought. I had to double check it as I have never written it but I do read something. What do you say here, companies respond if we ask them to send us low-level device specs?

Comment: Most likely they will tell you that the details are proprietary and they are unwilling to share them with you. But it never hurts to ask. You should look for a different WiMax modem that supports OSX and Linux. If you really want to learn to write device drivers, start with an easier project that is well documented.

Comment: Learning by something that will help the community is most interesting I believe so I will first ask them to see if they can send me a report about how the device can communicate.

Comment: One thing, they say the greenpacket devices are IEEE 802.16e compliant. Won't this help?

Comment: The Greenpacket device allows your computer to speak the IEEE 802.16e protocol. But that doesn't help you communicate with the Greenpacket device. Regarding doing useful work for the community - that is an admirable goal, but you have to walk before you can run.

Comment: One other thing - if Greenpacket *is* willing to share the USB communication protocol for their device with you, they will probably require you to sign an NDA. That will prevent you from releasing your source code to the public.

Comment: I can do that. My driver would help the community by using it. I don't think they would need the source code.